# myfile.csproj don't run in NUnit-GUI

Tags: c#, import, nunit, nunit-gui

How to import my test files into the NUnit-GUI? When I open my myfile.csproj the run state is `Not Runnable`.

Comment: Build the project and open the assembly / dll that's created in NUnit-GUI, not the .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, but it sounds as if you are talking about the new NUnit GUI that is under development at https://github.com/NUnitSoftware/nunit-gui

The GUI depends on the nunit engine to load and run tests. The bare engine does not support loading project files but requires installation of an extension in order to do so. In the case of console execution, there are packages that bundle some of the extensions and you may be familiar with that.

For the GUI there is no such easy way to install extensions yet but it is under development. Bear in mind that the NUnit 3 GUI is software under development in a pre-alpha stage.

Hopefully, this helps you, even though it's not a very positive answer.